# Why is the container overlapping my sidebar-ish <nav>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Why is the fluid-container overlapping like that, but others don't?
Is that correct, or am I missing something? Looks wrong to me.

```
<nav class="nav flex-column float-left">
  {links}
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid"><!-- overlapping -->
  <div class="row"><!-- fine -->
    <div class="col"><!-- fine -->
      <main role="main"><!-- fine -->
      {content}
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w3LwwxL7/

[image: main container overlapping nav]

Edit: Just for you to know: I want to achieve a static left sidebar/nav with a fixed width (see image). Everything on the right is main content. That's why I didn't used col-1 (nav) and col-11 (main). Hope this helps :-)

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? 4 or 3?

Comment: le bootstrapo 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your sidenav a fixed `width` and set a `padding-left` (same amount of sidebar width)

Here is an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/w3LwwxL7/3/